# The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: .net, docker, ssl, .net-core, nuget

While doing a docker build on my .NET Core project, I got the following error on all my NuGets:

> 80.19 /app/GradingTool.Tests/GradingTool.Tests.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain [/app/GradingTool.sln]
>
> #12 80.20 /app/GradingTool.Tests/GradingTool.Tests.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired. [/app/GradingTool.sln]
>
> #12 80.20 /app/GradingTool.Tests/GradingTool.Tests.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain [/app/GradingTool.sln]

I never had this error before,
Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:latest
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgdiplus libc6-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:4200"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="Credentials/SchoolTools-e9f260bdf56e.json"
ENV VIRTUAL_HOST="eva.schooltools.lu,www.eva.schooltools.lu,schooltools.lu,www.schooltools.lu"
ENV LETSENCRYPT_HOST="eva.schooltools.lu,www.eva.schooltools.lu,schooltools.lu,www.schooltools.lu"
ENV LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL="wilson.silva@edutec.lu"
EXPOSE 4200
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GradingTool.dll"]
```

Comment: How does your dockerfile and project look like?

Comment: I added the docker file, but what do you mean by project look like?

Comment: Content of `GradingTool.Tests.csproj`. Why do you need to install nodejs and libgdiplus?

Comment: My Projects has 4 Solutions, GradingTool.Tests.csproj, GradingTool.Core.csproj, GradingTool.Data.csproj and GradingTool.csproj

Comment: Watch https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates

Comment: Actual resolution: https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49 (tl;dr Debian broke things, not NuGet).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the Dockerfile file, I changed from

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine
```

This worked for me!

Comment: It's worth highlighting that this moves from a Debian based to Alpine based docker-image so there may be slight differences in the base packages etc so this may get rid of the immediate error but could introduce harder to track down issues in the long run.

Comment: This change is a bit more hairy in projects that use gRPC. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18338

Answer (score 42):

Update: Check this announcement: https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49

At the moment the issue appears to be related to the Debian image.

Switch to an Ubuntu or Alpine based image instead:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build-env
```

Follow https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates.

Comment: FYI MS have made an announcement about some interim images until the problem is resolved: https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49

Comment: Just wondering: do you guys think this is something which is taking them long to fix? I just now upgraded our project to .net 5 (not merged back into master ;) ) and realized it doesn't work anymore.. so basically: do you think this will be fixed in a few days or is it a matter of months?

Comment: @OschtärEi they published new images now as a workaround, check the comment on the announcement linked above. This requires you to modify the docker tag but it will still be debian based. I assume the main ones will take a bit.

Comment: This is not a Microsoft problem, it is a Debian problem.

Comment: @MartinUllrich yes I saw the workaround. I meant so you can use it without the workaround :)

Comment: I wonder is there any reason MS still use buster base image. Can't we just switch to alpine?

Answer (score 21):

**Short answer**

Replace `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest`

With `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.102-ca-patch-buster-slim-amd64`

Once they officially patch the certificate issue, go back to :latest.

**Long answer**

This is because of an issue in the Debian docker image you are using:
`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest`

The :latest tag is using a Debian image (5.0.102-1-buster-slim-amd64) and Debian released a patch that generated certificate issues.

The NuGet team published new pre-release Debian images that mitigate the ca-certificate issue. See the open issue & image replacements workarounds here:

https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49#issuecomment-768766265

Later on they'll publish the release version of SDK images (once the Debian ca-certificates package is released in Debian 10 Buster).

Using the :focal tag (Ubuntu) might solve the issue for your .NET app as well, although you must consider you are not using Debian anymore.

**LATEST UPDATE:**
Microsoft published patched docker images using the conventional tags like sdk:5.0. It is safe to revert from :5.0.102-ca-patch-buster-slim-amd64 to :5.0

Answer (score 19):

I think nuget.org is having some issues with their certificate. I'm currently getting the following for all NuGet packages from nuget.org

> error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 3.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
>
> error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata 3.1.2' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: You are getting the same error as me, did nuget.org say something about it?

Comment: They have not, however all our projects on our build server is suddenly reporting NU3028 & NU3037 for all packages from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json for some reason

Comment: Yes, In their GitHub Repo under Issues there are many people having the same issue as us so hopefully they will fix it soon enough! Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Opened https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for it

Answer (score 19):

As already mentioned the current updates of issue could be followed here:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491
To shorten your journey
Known workarounds include:

- Downgrade to .NET Core 3.1
- If using docker, change your base image from "FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0" to "
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal" or "
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine"
- Put this inside the  tag in your nuget.config to disable validation altogether (works with dotnet restore) :

> <config> <add key="signatureValidationMode" value="accept" />

You can also check the status here: https://status.nuget.org/

Answer (score 12):

This change also works:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal
```

Answer (score 5):

Better to go from Debian to Ubuntu and skip Alpine as .net Regions and Cultures are missing from Alpine!  i.e sdk:5.0-focal is your best bet and does indeed fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to change your base image, another way to fix this is to install the `ca-certificates` package.

Add this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     ca-certificates \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& sed -i '$ d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Of course, this can be removed again as soon as the underlying issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered below error in dotnet sdk 5.0.201.

> error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.

After I update the sdk to 5.0.401 and rebuild it then it is working fine.

Comment: This worked for me; according to this issue https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 any version after 5.0.204 is good.