# Micrtosoft dotnet sdk5.0 docker image having certificate untrusted root issues on build?

Tags: docker, nuget, certificate, root

Hi I have logged the following issue with MS GitHub repo for their docker images, looks like these maybe a nuget root cert issue? is anyone aware of any issue or is it me?!

Thanks for anyone's help!

Full detail of problem here:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2548

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919460/the-author-primary-signatures-timestamp-found-a-chain-building-issue-untrusted)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the issue appears to be related to the Debian image.

Switch to an Ubuntu or Alpine based image instead, e.g.:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal
```

Follow https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates.